# need help on datetime function in java

Tags: java, datetime, format

I am trying to using the `getHours()` function in the `Date` class in Java, but it always shows "The method `getHours()` from the type `Date` is deprecated".

How do I format the datetime to yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm and add 8 hours in the time display? After this I need to `getHours()` for some compare function.
My code is given below, but has some errors and doesn't work...

```
SimpleDateFormat Dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm" );

Date dateA = new Date();
Date in8Hours = new Date( dateA.getTime() + 8L * Timer.ONE_HOUR );
String systimeNow = Dateformat.format( in8Hours ).toString();
Date systimeNowA = Dateformat.parse( systimeNow );
if (systimeNowA.getHours() >= 13)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Calendar instead, which is not deprecated:

```
Calendar systimeNowA = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = systimeNowA .get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

How to get the format:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
String formattedOutput= dateFormat.format(systimeNowA .getTime());
```

Comment: for using calendar.. may I know how to format it become ( "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm" ) format?